# Unity3d app hides facebook dialog

Tags: facebook, iframe, unity-game-engine

I'm deploying a unity3d webplayer, and the new right panel (Ticker) in Facebook can prompt dialog in Like, and Recommend etc. However, those dialog gets cut off and hidden by the unity app. This seems like a known issue since early days, is there a good solution.

Comment: the only solution i have found is to have all my like / rec buttons on the left side of my pages near top.  "Placement is solution."

Comment: Hey Robin,Did you manage to solve the problem?